# JAXB to JSON when using JAVAFX

Tags: json, javafx, jaxb

I´m building an GUI with Javafx and i was able to create a DataOutput to xml.
But now, i like to parse everything to JSON.

To save data to a File I used a Marshaller:

```
try {
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext
                .newInstance(FirmenListWrapper.class);
        Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
        m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

        FirmenListWrapper wrapper = new FirmenListWrapper();
        wrapper.setPersons(firmenData);

        m.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, "/json");
        m.marshal(wrapper, file);

        setFirmaFilePath(file);
    } catch (Exception e) {
```

but it´s not working like this. Any Idea why?

my FirmenWrapper looks like this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "firmen")
public class FirmenListWrapper {

    private List<Firmen> firmen;

    @XmlElement(name = "firmen")
    public List<Firmen> getFirmen() {
        return firmen;
    }

    public void setFirmen(List<Firmen> firmen) {
        this.firmen = firmen;
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: So you want to unmarshal the JSON file? Or?

Comment: First I like to marshal the object to json (to save it in a json.file)  and then i like to load my json-data(unmarshal) into my gui. My try to marshal the data to json(the code i have posted) is not working.

the Idea is, to have save-button to save my gui-data into a json.file in jsonformat and it should be possible to load other jsonfiles too.

I hope this makes my problem a bit more clearly.